# Remove the last 2 characters from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm collecting all my user's email addresses for a mass mailing like this:

```
def self.all_email_addresses
  output = ''
  User.all.each{|u| output += u.email + ", " }
      output
end
```

However, I end up with an extra ", " on the string of email addresses.

How can I get rid of this / is there a better way to get a comma separated list of email addresses?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use join:

```
def self.all_email_addresses
  User.all.collect {|u| u.email}.join ', '
end
```

Comment: I jumped the gun a bit, this is what I was going for :P

Comment: Always remembering that in Rails (and Ruby 1.9?) you can code-golf this a little to User.all.map(&:email).join(', ')

Comment: still you can make it nicer with:

User.all.map(&:email) * ", "

Answer (score 29):

### remove the last two characters

```
str.chop.chop # ...or...
str[0..-3]
```

Although this does answer the exact question, I agree that it isn't the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes. To be used with care though, each chop is a brand new string.

Answer (score 13):

Or just "yadayada"[0..-3] will do it.